# In Python, if I make a list of Optional values and then filter out None, how do I convince the type checker the list can't contain None?

Tags: python

In Python, when collecting a sequence of `Optional` values into an `Iterable` or `List` while filtering out `None` values, how do you express to the typechecker that the element type of the resulting `Iterable` is no longer `Optional` and the list does not contain `None`s?

Take the following example:

```
def a(i: InputType) -> Optional[ResultType]:
   ...

def b(is: List[InputType]) -> Iterable[ResultType]:
    return filter(partial(is_not, None), (a(x) for x in is))
```

The type checker (Pyright in my case) complains that I can't put the potential `None` value in the `Iterable[ScanFileResult]` return type. But since I'm filtering it out, I need some way to assert to prove to the typechecker that the element type is no longer `Optional[ResultType]` but just `ResultType`. What's the cleanest way of doing this?

Comment: Does type inference work for `return (ax for ax in (a(x) for x in xs) if ax is not None)`?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq great suggestion! I would just add that if using python 3.10+ `return (ax for x in xs if (ax:=a(x)) is not None` avoids the need to loop twice over the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @MateenUlhaq in the comments the problem you are facing is probably due to the use of `filter(partial(is_not, None))` that makes it hard for the language server to infer the type of ots return value.

You can make it easier for it by filtering out the `None`s at the beginning.
The following is an example:

```py
def a(x: int) -> int | None:
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return x
    return None

def b(xs: list[int]):
    print(sum(xs))

xs = [ax for x in range(10) if (ax:=a(x)) is not None]
b(xs)
```

With this pyright does not complain since it can infer the type of `xs` to be `list[int]`

Applying this to your specific case you would get something like:

```py
def b(inputs: List[InputType]) -> Iterable[ResultType]:
    return (ax for x in inputs if (ax:=a(x)) is not None)
```

This works on python version 3.10+ (as it uses the `:=` operator).

Comment: Thanks Mateen Ulhaq and Matteo Zanoni -- this worked, the type checker understands the explicit expression with the walrus operator. A neat solution!